# Akka - preStart method called infinite times

Tags: akka

I'm new to akka and I can't figure out why the preStart is called infinite times.

The preStart method for my actor is:

```
    public void preStart() {
        System.out.println(getSelf() + "in preStart()");
        final ActorSelection firstplayer = getContext().actorSelection("akka://DistributedSystem@127.0.0.1:27001/user/firstplayer");
        firstplayer.tell(new Msg(), getSelf());
    }
```

The message is received from firstplayer, as it should.
The println is logged infinite times so the method is called infinite times, however if I leave out the last line of code (`firstplayer.tell(new Msg(), getSelf());`) the method is called just once (as I expected it to do).

I create the actor in the main method, with
`system.actorOf(Props.create(Player.class),"player");`

Comment: That sounds strange. I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code you shared, which makes me suspect perhaps the problem might be elsewhere in your code. Could you share a small example project that shows the problem?

Comment: I completely changed my code and don't use the preStart method anymore. 
I think the problem was there was something that made my actor die immediately and restart, so each time it restarted it called the preStart method. Thank you for your comment!